# an integral inequality problem of my thesis

Tags: real-analysis

we suppose that $f:R^+\rightarrow R^+$ is a positive Lebesgue integrable function and for every $\epsilon >0$, $\int_0^\epsilon f(s)ds >0$ .if  we have $\sqrt[n]{\int_0^a f(s)ds} <1$ ($0<a<1$), then we want to prove the following inequality
$\int_0^{\sqrt[n]{a}} f(s)ds\leq \sqrt[n]{\int_0^a f(s)ds} $

Comment: Is the inequality true? Suppose $f(x)$ has mean value $1.6$ over $0<x<\frac14$ and over $\frac14<x<\frac12$, but mean value $0.2$ over $\frac12<x<1$; this $f$ seems to fit the requirements (if $a<1$ then $\int_0^a f <1$, hence $(\int_0^a f)^{1/n} <1$), but taking $a=\frac14$ and $n=2$, we have $\sqrt[n]a = \frac12$ and the inequality to prove becomes $\int_0^{1/2} f(s)ds\leq \sqrt{\int_0^{1/4} f(s)ds}$, equivalent to $0.8 \leq \sqrt{0.4}$, which is false. Did I miss something?